# Why "and []" is True and "or []" is False

Tags: haskell, monoids

Why "and" on an empty list returns true, does it imply that an empty list holds True? Sorry but I cannot read and comprehend this correctly, so please correct me. Thanks.

```
Prelude> and []
True
Prelude> or []
False
```

Comment: In both cases the answer is the identity for the operation

Comment: @FrederickCheung could you please expand your answer, sorry but I do not understand what you mean by identity for the operation?

Comment: that's the definition if you read it like : "and xs is true if all elements of xs are true" which is the case in your example, and "or xs is true if any of its elements is true" which is not the case in the example

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In mathematics, it's often useful to talk about a binary operation, such as `&&`, `||`, `+`, `*`, etc as having an *identity*.  The identity is a value `e` such that the following property holds for some generic binary operation `<>`

```
e <> x = x
x <> e = x
```

For the operators I listed above, they are *commutative*, meaning that `x <> y = y <> x` for all `x` and `y`, so we only have to check one of the above properties.  For `and`, the binary operator in question is `&&`, and for `or` the binary operator is `||`.  If we make a [Cayley table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) for these operations, it would look like

```
&&    | False | True
------+-------+------
False | False | False
True  | False | True


||    | False | True
------+-------+------
False | False | True
True  | True  | True
```

So as you can see, for `&&` if you have `True && False` and `True && True`, the answer is always the second argument to `&&`.  For `||`, if you have `False || False` and `False || True`, the answer is always the second argument, so the first argument of each must be the identity element under those operators.  Put simply:

```
True && x = x
x && True = x

False || x = x
x || False = x
```

Thus, the preferred answer when there are no elements to perform the operator on is the identity element for each operation.

---

It might help to also think about the identity elements for `+` and `*`, which are `0` and `1` respectively:

```
x + 0 = x = 0 + x
x * 1 = x = 1 * x
```

You can also extend this to operations like list concatenation (`++` with `[]`), function composition for functions of type `a -> a` (`(.)` with `id`), along with many others.  Since this is starting to look like a pattern, you might ask if this is already a thing in Haskell, and indeed it is.  The module `Data.Monoid` defines the `Monoid` typeclass that abstracts this pattern, and it's minimal definition is

```
class Monoid a where
    mempty :: a                   -- The identity
    mappend :: a -> a -> a        -- The binary operator
```

And it even aliases `mappend` as `<>` for ease of use (it was no accident that I choose it above for a generic binary operator).  I encourage you to look at that module and play around with its definitions.  The source code is quite easy to read and is enlightening.

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr for taking your time and explaining this in such detail. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

`and` and `or` are just folds, and a fold called on an empty list will produce its starting argument, which is `True` or `False`, respectively.

They are implemented using a fold only if `Prelude` is loaded, otherwise they are realised using explicit recursion, which in itself still is a fold despite not actually making use of `foldr` or `foldl`. They still behave the same as we can see by examining the source:

```
and [] = True
and (x:xs) = x && and xs
or [] = False
or (x:xs) = x || or xs
```

---

[Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#and) is a link to the implementations.

---

To clear the confusion in the comments: A fold is a function which takes a binary function and a starting value (often called accumulator) and traverses a list until it is empty. When called on an empty list, the fold will return the accumulator as is where it does not matter if the list has already been traversed or not. This is a sample implementation of `foldr`:

```
foldr _ acc [] = acc
foldr f acc (x:xs) = f x (foldr f acc xs)
```

`and` is simply

```
and = foldr (&&) True
```

which makes `and []` evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Sorry but starting argument is null for an empty list, right? so how calling a "and" fold on an empty list yields True?

Comment: @RohitSharma No, the starting argument for a fold is the first accumulator value, which is ``True`` for ``and`` and ``False`` for ``or``.

Comment: A relevant note would be that XOR has no identity, so you can't (or at least the libraries don't) define `xor :: [Bool] -> Bool`. There is however [`xor :: NonEmpty Bool -> Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.15.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:xor), which doesn't need the identity because there must be at least one element in the list!

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense! Thanks.

Comment: @leftaroundabout XOR does have an identity element though. `xor False b == b` for all values of `b`.

Comment: @LambdaFairy: hum, that's hard to deny. \*Scratch head\* Why there should be `xor :: NonEmpty Bool -> Bool` but not `xor :: [Bool] -> Bool` then, I don't understand.

Answer (score 7):

Excellent answers, but I think it's worth providing a more intuitive treatment.  Instead of `and :: [Bool] -> Bool`, however, let's look at `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool`.  You can think of `all` this way.  Picture the predicate (the `a -> Bool` argument) as a *hypothesis* about list elements.  Then `all` returns `False` if and only if the list contains at least one *counterexample* to the hypothesis.  If the list is empty there are no counterexamples, so it's trivially confirmed.

To bring it back to `and`, note that `and` and `all` are interdefinable.  If you have `and`, you can define `all` this way:

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all pred = and . map pred
```

And vice-versa, if you already had `all`, you could define `and` from it:

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = all id
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @bheklilr answer, let's recall that a Monoid is a tuple `(M,e,<>)`, where `M` is a object (you can think of it as a type), `e` is a point of the object `M` (`e : M` - element of type) and `<>` is a binary operation, which is associative and has `e` as identity:

```
<> : M -> M -> M
e <> x = x
x <> e = x
(x <> y) <> z = x <> (y <> z)
```

There are monoid homomorphisms between some monoids. There is one free monoid - the monoid from which there is a homomorphism into any other. Such free monoid is a list: `([a], [], ++)` can be mapped into any other monoid. For example:

```
([Int], [], ++) => (Int, 0, +)
([Int], [], ++) => (Int, 1, *)
([Bool], [], ++) => (Bool, True, &&)
([Bool], [], ++) => (Bool, False, ||)
```

Then `sum`, `product`, `and`, `or` are the respective monoid homomorphisms, mapping the elements of the types `[Int]` and `[Bool]`. By the definition of the monoid homomorphism, the mapping `h` of the monoids is performed in such a way that any list `x++y` is mapped into the point `h(x ++ y) == (h x) <> (h y)` - for example, `and (x++[]) == (and x) && (and [])`. It becomes clear from the latter example, that since `x++[] == x`, so `(and x) && (and []) == and x`, therefore, `and []` maps into the identity element of `(Bool, True, &&)`.

Comment: @dfeuer "point of an object" is in terms of category theory. You could say roughly an element of a set, or an instance of a type.

Comment: I have some sense of an "object" in category theory, but not a "point" of one.

Answer (score 4):

One way to think about `True` and `False` is as elements of the [lattice](http://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Lattice) ordered by `False < True`. `&&` and `||` can be viewed as the binary "meet" (greatest lower bound) and "join" (least upper bound) operations for this lattice. Similarly, `and` and `or` are general finite meet and finite join operations. What is `and []`? It's the greatest lower bound of `[]`. But `True` is (vacuously) less than or equal to every element of `[]`, so it's a lower bound of `[]`, and (of course) it's greater than any other lower bound (the other being `False`), so `and [] = True`. The algebraic view (thinking about monoids and such) turns out to be entirely equivalent to the order-theoretic view, but I think the order-theoretic one offers more visual intuition.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of `and` is to find the first entry in the list which is `False`. If the entry is not found, the result is `True`. For example:

```
and $ map even [2..]
```

will not iterate through the whole infinite list, but will stop at `3` and return `False`. There is no `False` element in the empty list, so we default to `True`.

For `or` it's similarly: it tries to find the first `True` and then stops, otherwise it's `False`.

Answer (score 1):

`and` means: "Is everything there `True`?". When it's empty, everything's that is in there (which isn't much) is true, so that's a yes (`True`).

`or` means: "Is anything there `True`?". When there's nothing there, there's nothing true there. (`False`)