# Checking for Values in a List to See if Coprime with a Single Variable

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am having some trouble implementing this function in Haskell. Here is what I have so far:

```
--Extend coprime to a function on lists:
--coprime_with n list = True exactly when n is coprime with
--every element of list.

coprime_with :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
coprime_with a [] = False
coprime_with a (b:bs) = if ((coprime a b) == True) then 
                          (coprime_with a bs)
                        else False
```

Hopefully this isn't too confusing. Please don't just give me the answer. Just let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. Thanks!

EDIT: Okay so I figured it out! Thank you so much for the response. It was incredibly fast. I am a Comp Sci major and this is my first semester. My goal is to actually learn and not just get through it. I appreciate your response and how you worded it.

My problem was this:

```
coprime_with a [] = False
```

when it should have been this:

```
coprime_with a [] = True
```

Now it is working properly. Phew... I feel pretty stupid that it just took me five hours to write this function, but at least I actually learned something. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide an example input with an expected output, along with the current output?

Comment: A side note, `if ((coprime a b) == True) then ...` is the same as `if coprime a b then ...`.  The parentheses are not needed, and once you have a `Bool` there's no need to compare it to another `Bool`.

Comment: I think I see your mistake.  As a hint: what does `and []` return in GHCi?  Why does it return that?  How does that compare to your function?

Comment: Hint: your function definition never mentions `True`, nor it performs operations on booleans, hence...

Comment: You should add the answer to this question yourself (as you found it) so that you can mark the answer later (let's clean up a bit)

Comment: Take it to the next level and write it with [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:all)! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Great that you've found your problem. There's few more lessons you can take from this.

so you now have

```
coprime_with :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
coprime_with a []     = True
coprime_with a (b:bs) = if ((coprime a b) == True) then 
                          (coprime_with a bs)
                        else False
```

whenever you see *if **A** then **B** else **False***, you can replace it with ***A*** && **B**. Do you see why?

whenever you see ***A*** == **True**, you can replace it with just ***A***. Do you see why?

So now we have

```
coprime_with a (b:bs) = (coprime a b) && (coprime_with a bs)
```

The parameter `a` doesn't ever change, but we pass it on and on to every recursive invocation, needlessly. On the other hand, we *must* have it, as it is what `coprime_with` is all about. The solution is to introduce an internal function,

```
coprime_with a bs = g bs      -- "g" is "coprime_with a"
   where
     g []     = True
     g (b:bs) = coprime a b && g bs
```

(we can write it without the parentheses as functional application in Haskell has the highest priority).

this is known as [worker/wrapper transform](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Worker_wrapper). It makes our code cleaner, and lets compiler to perform more optimizations, potentially. Our new `g` is the worker, and `coprime_with` is the wrapper as it wraps `g` inside. `g` has a different type, and `coprime_with` takes care of feeding it the proper arguments (here just the second one), and transforming its results back into what expected (here just passing them along).

Next, we can give a new name, in Haskell, to whatever (sub-)expression we want. Here, we'll do

```
coprime_with a bs = g pred bs    -- "pred" is for "predicate"
   where
     g pred []     = True
     g pred (b:bs) = pred b && g pred bs
     pred = coprime a
```

what's the point to this? we're back at passing an extra parameter on recursion, you ask? Correct! This is not an optimization, but just a re-write, aiming to get *somewhere*. Next, we can even substitute back the definition of `pred`

```
coprime_with a bs = g (coprime a) bs
   where
     g :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
     g pred []     = True
     g pred (b:bs) = pred b && g pred bs
```

and that's our destination. What's left is to realize that we've reinvented a wheel (one of many). You can find what it is by [searching for `g`'s type on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+Bool) and examining the sources for the few top matches there to see which one is our `g` exactly. Hint: you already were suggested its use, in the comments.

---

Now we can see clearly why it is `True` and not `False` that must be returned in the empty list case. Our `g` checks to see whether the predicate holds for all elements of the list. In other words, it must fail (meaning *here*, return `False`) if some element in the list fails the predicate — and so, return `True` otherwise! But there are no elements in the empty list, to fail the predicate.

(another explanation for this issue that I like [basically says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427590/why-and-is-true-and-or-is-false/25429456#25429456), because `g (a++b) == g a && g b` and `a == a ++ []`, it must hold `g a == g (a++[]) == g a && g []`).

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are looking for is to change

```
coprime_with a [] = False
```

to

```
coprime_with a [] = True
```

When the list was getting to the final recursive stage, it had turned into an empty list. The fact that it made it to the empty stage meant that all the numbers inside the list had been coprime. However, the parameters were set up in such a way that when the list was empty, it was set to read a "False". Simply changing that condition to "True" fixed the issue.